# python failure in loading modules from sitepackages

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have installed a package from python using pip.  When i'm trying to load that module failed with errors.

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Dec 22 2016, 12:23:20)
[GCC 4.8.5] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import delphixpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/oracle/Envs/delphix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/delphixpy/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import web
ImportError: No module named 'web'
```

---

When i look towards the folder, i could see the folders available  in the site-packages/delphixpy/

I see the file **init**.py available in each and every subfolder as well.   Still it is failing loading the modules.

Regards,
Ramesh G

Comment: error is `No module named 'web'`

Comment: That module is trying to load some other module called `web` in the global 'namespace', and your Python doesn't have it.

Comment: I've run into this with a couple different packages.  I just tested with this delphixpy package.  I installed to my Py3.6 build and my Py2.7 build, both using PIP.  Imported just fine in 2.7, failed with the same error as OP in 3.6.  In all cases I've seen it, it doesn't seem like there should be an error.  Anyone have more experience with the package management of python 2 vs python 3?

Comment: What is the `pip` command that you used? If you didn't run `pip` by its full/relative path path, could you post the output of `which pip`? Because the path where it searches for the _web_ module is: _/home/oracle/Envs/delphix/lib/python3.5/site-packages_.